# issue with font-face firefox and IE

Tags: html, css, web, font-face

In a website i have entered the font "Helvetica", using the font-face function with Google Chrome and Safari no problem while, when i feel to see the web site in Firefox and IE i have a problem. The browser loads the font, but instead of seeing the characters i see incomprehensible dashes and rows .
Searching in Google i have found this solution;
i have changed the Aruba's .htaccess with the following commands:

```
# BEGIN REQUIRED FOR webfonts

AddType font/ttf .ttf
AddType font/eot .eot
AddType font/otf .otf
AddType font/woff .woff

<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff)$">
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</ IfModule>
</ FilesMatch>

# END REQUIRED FOR webfonts
```

this in theory had to solve my problem, but this hasn't happened.
Does anyone have any other solution for it?

Comment: Does this happen with other fonts? I don’t think (the real) Helvetica can legally be used as a web font, and some browsers might check this.

Comment: For now I have had this problem only with Helvetica, what you said can be a possibility. But i have seeen that many other have this problem with Helvetica or other Font type using Font-face in CSS

Comment: More cleanly: Helvetica Neue Light (actually, every Helvetica variant) is an Adobe font which is not licensed for web distribution. You cannot legally host it as a web font. It is, however, preinstalled on modern Mac computers, so you can simply include it for Mac users with a regular `font-family:` property. [Google Web Fonts](http://www.google.com/webfonts) also has [Open Sans](http://www.google.com/webfonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,400,300), which is pretty close for your Windows and Linux viewers.

Comment: @joequincy He sees Helvetica in the other browsers so it must be installed on his system for that to happen. The other browsers should be able to use it.

Comment: @Rob ... yes, because he's probably using a Mac, or copied it off a Mac (also illegal, I might add, as the license prohibits it). Or he's using the font but can't recognize the difference between it and Arial (the Windows default, and thus what Webkit uses if `@font-face` provides a corrupted font file, which is likely considering the comments on minitech's answer). **However** it is not possible to get that font onto a Windows or Linux machine LEGALLY without the end user paying Adobe to license it, so it's better to seek out a different font to deliver to those users.

Comment: Infact i have taken from my Mac the font Helvetica, and with the web site http://onlinefontconverter.com/ i have converted the font in .ttf,.woff,.svg,.eot and i so i can use it with font-face. The font is not corrupted because i see right in Chome and Safari but not in Firefox and IE

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be a space before or after the `/` in the MIME type, and the `.` belongs immediately before the extension, not after the MIME type. And I'd make them all lowercase, too.

Comment: No, but in fact in my code is written as you say, so that:        
AddType font/ttf .ttf
AddType font/eot .eot
AddType font/otf .otf
AddType font/woff .woff
I was wrong the first to write

Comment: @user1880684: What does your CSS look like?

Comment: In the sense that errors in my css spacing written above are not there, the .htaccess file is written right.I wanted to know if there was another way to solve my problem.

Comment: @Bobsus88: I'm asking for your CSS stylesheet, though, because it's probably the one at fault.

Comment: No, i am sure that my CSS stylesheet is correct, and this is not the problem. Another reason of my security is that other person have had the same problem with the same CSS stylesheet!!

Comment: @Bobsus88: If you don't want help, that's fine.

Comment: But i want help, but i have only said that my CSS stylesheet is correct because it is the same of other people.  If you say that my CSS is incorrect, good, but you must say me where is the error. Thank you and sorry did not want to be rude.

Comment: @Bobsus88: I don't know where the error is in your CSS file; I don't know if there is an error. (Mind, I would just like to see the `@font-face` section for Helvetica - not the whole thing.) Even if you're pretty sure it's the same as other ones - mistakes can still be made, even with filesystem layout. Just eliminating all the possibilities. So... please? :)

Comment: I didn't realize that you wanted to read the CSS stylesheet for to see @font-face, sorry for this misunderstanding. <!-- language:css@font-face {
    font-family: 'helveticaneue';
    src: url('font/HelveticaNeueLight.eot');
    src: url('font/HelveticaNeueLight.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('font/HelveticaNeueLight.woff') format('woff'),
         url('font/HelveticaNeueLight.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('font/HelveticaNeueLight.svg#HelveticaNeueLight') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}lang-none-->

Comment: @Bobsus88: How did you convert the font to different formats? (It might have made a mistake.)

Comment: I have use this web-site http://onlinefontconverter.com/, here you can convert any font in any format you want. I don't think that is the problem because i have already used for more other font and another thing, on my pc i see the right font but with the pc of my friends i see dashes and rows.

Comment: @Bobsus88: On *all* browsers on your PC? Also, is it possible for you to take a screenshot of the dashes and rows?

Comment: Really, i don't understand where is the error. This also because the same solution to change the .htaccess file for some user is right for other is wrong!!!

Comment: On all browser on my PC i see the right helvetica font, while on pc's friends the problem there is with Firefox and IE while Chrome and Safari there isn't this error. Because the browser-compatibility is very important, this for me is a problem. Now i can't give you the screenshoot because in Italy is night and my friend is sleeping :) Tomorrow morning i can give you a screenshot

Comment: I was able to take the screenshot, you can see at this link http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7488878/Cattura1.JPG, from the image you can see the font is loaded through firebug but you can see the text between the two images

Comment: Reload that page with the NET panel visible, then make sure the font is loading properly ( [see highlighted area](http://i3.photobucket.com/albums/y60/joequincy/font.png) ). The font should have a legible preview. If it does not, then most likely the font file itself is corrupted.

Comment: @Bobsus88: What he said :)

Comment: The font is not corrupted because i see right in Chrome and Safari and also the font with NET panel is loaded properly, you can see from the screnshot  http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7488878/Cattura1.JPG

Comment: @Bobsus88: But Chrome and Safari might be using a different format of the font than Firefox or IE that's not corrupted.

Comment: Ok, but with my Firefox and IE i see the font helvetica, the problem is when how my friends see the web site with Firefox and IE don't see the font. I would understand because i see the font helvetica and other no with the same browser version!!

Comment: @Bobsus88: Do you have the font installed on your computer? Uninstall it temporarily and see what happens. And make sure to clear your cache.

Comment: Yes i have installed Helvetica on my computer, i have temporarily disabled helvetica and i am in the same situation.

Comment: @Bobsus88: Then it would seem that the problem is with the font files. Try FontSquirrel's generator instead, just to make sure: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator